# How to delete all but the last 50 SQLite items in Android

Tags: android

I want to delete all but the last 50 items in SQLite

Currently, the data after 50 is deleted after searching the db with the for statement.

Is there an easy way to achieve your goals?

Comment: please ask the question clearly. can you elaborate the context?

Comment: So those 50 data, do they have something in common, or do they follow any order?